# Showing the selected file path/names in window - cocoa programming

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I am new to cocoa programming, Using the below code I want to show the selected file names in window. How can I do that?

```
- (IBAction)selectFile:(id)sender {

    int i; // Loop counter.

    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    NSArray *fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wmv", @"3gp", @"mp4", @"avi", @"mp3", @"mma", @"wav", nil];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    //Enable multiple selection of files
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil types:fileTypes] == NSOKButton )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"filename::: %@", fileName);

            // Do something with the filename.
        }
    }
}
```

In NSLog I am getting the names, what I want is to show the names on window too, to show the user that these files are selected.

Which view can be used? What is the way to achieve this?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSTextView` or an `NSTextField`.

Comment: It will be showing whatever text you put into it.  If you want one filename per line, put a newline (`\n`) after each filename.

Comment: can you help me with code, that how can I display this NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames]; in NSTextView

Comment: Try to figure it out yourself.  If you can't, come back and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
NSString* fileName;
    // Loop through all the files and process them.
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        fileName =[fileName stringByAppendingString:[files objectAtIndex:i];

        // Do something with the filename.
    }

        NSLog(@"filename::: %@", fileName);
      textView.text=fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

`runModalForDirectory:file:types:` is deprecated in *OS X v10.6.* You could use `runModal` instead. 
You can set path using `setDirectoryURL:`, and you can set fileTypes using `setAllowedFileTypes:`.